# Facebook Login settings : Where is the "Enable Client Access Token Flow" switch?

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/accesstokens) they say

> In your app's dashboard, there is a switch labeled Enable Client
>   Access Token Flow

Well, there not such a switch. Is there ? How can I enable/disable this switch ?

[image]

Comment: Products -> Facebook Login

Comment: Sorry I cannot find it in here... could you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: -> Add Product ...

Comment: I have "Facebook Login" but no such thing as "Enable Client Access Token Flow" in it !

Comment: Your turn to show a screenshot.

Comment: Done, post edited

Comment: Ah, I see now, you are not actually talking about FB login settings, but about Account Kit settings. So, add Account Kit.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out... My goal was actually to achieve Facebook Login securely... and I came upon those pages when I was looking for a way to get short lived authorization code for my app using iOS SDK... So I guess there is no way to get authorization code...

Comment: Well, you're looking in the wrong place. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ There's a chapter dedicated to login security as well.

Answer (score 2):

The docs are wrong or out of date. To get the Account Kit client token,

1. Go to your facebook developer dashboard.
2. Click "add product"
3. choose Account Kit client

Follow the prompts and you will find the Account Kit client token
[image: Account kit.]

Comment: Seriously dude. One of the richest companies in the world with the best programmers, still can't maintain their docs. I have been having a lot of problems because of the inconsistencies there.